# Node.JS newbie: how to export functions and use them in browserify modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, node-modules, browserify

Suppose I have this `simple.js` file:

```
function Square(x)
{
  return x * x;
}

function Cube(x) 
{ 
  return x * x * x; 
}
```

Note that this code doesn't actually do anything by itself, it just defines these two simple functions.

Now I want to `browserify` this file, so I get a .js file that I can include in a regular HTML file, and then use the `Square` and `Cube` functions in there.

My problem is I don't understand how `module.exports` or `exports` works, or what exactly it is supposed to represent or contain.

My goal is to be able to do this in a `example.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src='myfunctions.js'></script>
<script>
var x = Square(3);
var y = Cube(5);
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

But if I do 
`browserify simple.js > myfunctions.js`
 then the above script obviously doesn't work, the `Square` and `Cube` functions are not defined.

I understand I have to somehow export those functions, but I don't know how, and I also don't know how to address them from within the HTML script.

I'm guessing I have to do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src='myfunctions.js'></script>
<script>
const myFuncs = ...???... // not sure what this should be?!
var x = myFuncs.Square(3);
var y = myFuncs.Cube(5);
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

I also experimented with using `--s SomeSymbolName` in the `browserify` line, but I couldn't get it to work.

What's the right approach for this?

Answer (score 3):

Found it after some more messing around, I add this line to `simple.js` :

```
module.exports = { 'Square':Square, 'Cube':Cube };
```

Then I use `browserify` with a standalone symbol like this:

`browserify simple.js --standalone myFuncs > myfunctions.js`

And now I can include `myfunctions.js` in the HTML file, and use the functions from within JavaScript like this:

```
var x = myFuncs.Square(3);
var y = myFuncs.Cube(5);
```